# Bootstrap 12 column grid does not start on the left

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am currently using Bootstrap with Vue inside an App.vue file. When using Bootstrap, I realised that there is a lot of empty space on the left and right sides. I have attached an image below.
I used the default code from the Grid System website.I have ensured that under my Vue styles, there is no code there besides the red outline. I am still slightly confused why my cols do not start from the left. [image: Three Column Visual]

Could there possible be any other conflicting style properties in Vue that takes priority?

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: can you add CSS ?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly I am adding! I am using Vue, so I have not linked it to an external style.css page yet. I am adding it between `<style></style>` tags for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class container has max-width set by bootstrap at each major media query breakpoint. I suggest you to add a class named something like container_flexible to the container div and apply the following styles

```
container_flexible {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I don't know your specific case, but usually it is good to have a maximum width, so that the website won't strech itself out on big displays. If you want that, then you  can add it in there too.

Comment: This worked! After changing this, i went to look up and try the different container options Bootstrap has and `container-fluid` seems to work the best for me. For some reason, the default `container` appears to read my browser as a bit smaller than it actually is, hence the breakpoints were not as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `justify-content-start` to the row div

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Suggestion: replace `col-sm` to `col` if necessary

Comment: I did try this but there did not seem to be a difference. Am i right in expecting that by "default", bootstrap will have the 3 cols spaced out a lot more and fill up the whole screen?

Comment: Did you write any custom stylings for row class?

Comment: I currently do not! Changing the `container` to `container-fluid` worked for me. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That empty space get in **class="container"** bootstrap class.you can remove container class and use external css

Answer (score 0):

there is a class in bootstrap that center the text, you can use it after "row" calss

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, while it did center the text it was not what I am looking for! I am confused why the left most red box exists. There are only three items and the empty space there seems to be caused by some sort of padding I cannot find.